# Angular 4 ng-build

Tags: angular, angular-cli

Just curious, running `ng build --prod`, I do not have any uglify dependencies in my `package.json`, and when I do `ng eject` and check my `webpack.config.js` there is also no uglify.

My question: On `ng build --prod`, I can still see the code clearly within sources tab for browser and set up my break point. There is no obfuscation or uglify of the code, changing variables such as `let stackoverflow` to `let a`.

How do I do this? I've been looking around and not much detail.

PS: maybe uglify-js with webpack??

Comment: Are you running the app on your local dev server, i mean with npm start o npm run start??

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Why not just do the ahead of time compiled bundle?

run `ng build --prod --aot`

the bundle code should be minified

Comment: Using `ng build --prod` implies `--aot`  [Clicky](https://github.com/angular/angular-cli/wiki/build#--dev-vs---prod-builds)

Comment: turns out our jenkins was configured to build via ng build --environment prod, which wasn't correct.

Answer (score 0):

Try `ng build --prod --build-optimizer`

From [angular's blog](https://blog.angular.io/the-past-present-and-future-of-the-angular-cli-13cf55e455f8#d217) it removes "code that you aren’t reliant on".

[This site](https://www.npmjs.com/package/@angular-devkit/build-optimi) lists a number of other 'optimizations.'

Comment: What does --build-optimizer do?

Comment: --build-optimizer is beta and I saw it actually increased my load times.... I do not recommend it for now